# Where is Android Studio monitor workspace?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want open my Android database using SqlLite manager on mozilla.
I took some error when I tried to open Android Device Manager. The error log is in 1439225229207.txt file. I looked for the the reason and I found:

> java.io.IOException: The folder "C:\Users\Myname.android\monitor-workspace.metadata" is read-only.

Unfortunately i couldn't find monitor-workspace in .android file. I enabled show hidden files but it was'n still there.

What you advice?

Comment: "C:\Users\Myname.android\monitor-workspace.metadata" is read-only.

Comment: And so i want to it read and write:)

Comment: I want to follow database changes like Sql Server. Is it possible at SqlLite ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running android studio as administrator,